# How to filter subindex for aggregation in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I query an index with wildcard (`interactive*`) to get all documents for the two indices `interactive-foo*` & `interactive-bar*`.

For some of my aggregations all of the indices are relevant but for others only `interactive-foo*` **OR** `interactive-bar*`. So I just want to filter for these 'subindices' in the aggregation.

```
GET _search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2017-08-01 00:00:00",
              "lte": "2017-08-31 23:59:59"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "key": "SOME_KEY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    // This one should be filtered and just count for interactive-bar*
    "bar_count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "SOME_FIELD"
      }
    },
    // This one should be filtered and just count for interactive-foo*
    "foo_count": {
      "value_count": {
        "field": "SOME_FIELD"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `filter` aggregation like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
              "gte": "2017-08-01 00:00:00",
              "lte": "2017-08-31 23:59:59"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "key": "SOME_KEY"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "bar_count": {
      "filter": {
        "indices": {
          "indices": ["interactive-bar-*"]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bar_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "SOME_FIELD"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "foo_count": {
      "filter": {
        "indices": {
          "indices": ["interactive-foo-*"]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "foo_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "SOME_FIELD"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note though that the `indices` query has been deprecated in ES 5.0. What you should do instead is to use a `terms` query on the `_index` field and list all the indices you want to include in your aggregation, like this:

```
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "bar_count": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "_index": ["interactive-foo-2017.08.14", "interactive-foo-2017.08.15"]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bar_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "SOME_FIELD"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "foo_count": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "_index": ["interactive-bar-2017.08.14", "interactive-bar-2017.08.15"]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "foo_count": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "SOME_FIELD"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But unfortunately this doesn't work. I get this error { "type": "query_shard_exception", "reason": "Can only use prefix queries on keyword and text fields - not on [_index] which is of type [_index]", ...}

Comment: what if you replace `prefix` with `term`?

Comment: When i use the term i get zero `doc_count`. Meanwhile i think this is not possible with elasticsearch..

Comment: Nothing's impossible ;-) What are the exact names of your indices?

Comment: Well i have 2 indices: interactive-foo-* (with date appended e.g. `interactive-foo-2017.08.14`) and `interactive-bar-*` (same with date appended).

Comment: I created new alias according to this docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html but i still get zero doc_count

Comment: Hmm, I thought that was working once... See my updated answer.

Comment: Not really. I solved it by filtering for `index_type`. I was lucky and i added an index type at the beginning to each index.